# Default value isn't getting set for ExtJs Form Values

Tags: javascript, extjs

I must be doing something completely wrong, but the default value isn't getting set for the following ExtJs form:

```
var simple = new Ext.FormPanel({
        labelWidth: 75, // label settings here cascade unless overridden
        frame:true,
        title: 'Edit User',
        bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
        width: 350,
        defaults: {width: 230},
        defaultType: 'checkbox'
        items: [{
                inputType: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Email',
                name: 'user[email]',
                id: 'user_email',
                vtype: 'email',
                value: 'user@domain.com'
            },{
                inputType: 'password',
                fieldLabel: 'Password',
                name: 'user[password]',
                id: 'user_password',
                allowBlank: false,
                value: 'password'
            },{
                inputType: 'checkbox',
                boxLabel: 'Is One',
                labelSeparator: '',
                name: 'user[is_one]',
                checked: true
            },{
                inputType: 'checkbox',
                boxLabel: 'Is Two',
                labelSeparator: '',
                name: 'user[is_two]',
                checked: true
            },{
                inputType: 'hidden',
                name: 'authenticity_token',
                value: '<%= form_authenticity_token %>'
            },{
                inputType: 'hidden',
                name: '_method',
                value: 'put'
            }

        ],

        buttons: [{
            text: 'Save',
            handler: function(){
                if(simple.getForm().isValid()){
                    simple.getForm().submit({
                        url: '/users/<%= @user.id %>',
                        waitMsg: 'Saving...',
                        success: function(simple, o){
                            msg('Success', 'done');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        },{
            text: 'Cancel'
        }]
    });

    simple.render("user-form");
```

The defaultType seems to be the key.  If I have defaultType set to 'checkbox', the checkboxes get checked appropriately.  If I have defaultType set to 'textfield', the text fields get populated.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you must explicitly define the `xtype:checkbox` config option for the checkbox items on your form.

Quote from [ExtJS API Documentation](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/):

> If an xtype is not explicitly
>   specified, the defaultType for that
>   Container is used.

Comment: This was correct, though I'm still not sure why.  The controls were all rendering properly, they just didn't get the default value set.  Anyway, defaulting to textfield and specifying xtype=checkbox, instead of inputType=checkbox resolved the issue.

Comment: Please see my answer for clarification on this.

Answer (score 2):

`inputType` is not the appropriate config for this.  `xtype` would be more appropriate (and is what `defaultType` applies to).  If you read the docs for `FormPanel.defaultType`:

> "The default **xtype** of child
>   Components..."

Perhaps the config should actually be `defaultXType` to be more precise...  Anyway, while `inputType` is technically a valid config, it's actually sort of a lower level config used to directly modify the field's HTML type attribute (it's not commonly used).  So in your code you are actually creating checkbox Components but then altering their HTML type attributes, which is not what Ext is expecting.  Switch to `xtype` instead for all fields and everything should work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** use `xtype` instead of constructing the controls in the `items` array.  See accepted answer above.

Looks like the `defaultType` config parameter is provided for your convenience: it allows you to supply a config object in the items array instead of an "instantiated Component".  This means that you'll need to explicitly create other kinds of controls in your `items` array.  See the API documentation for [FormPanel](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.FormPanel).

Try this:

```
var simple = new Ext.FormPanel({
    /* snip */
    defaultType: 'checkbox',
    items: [
        new Ext.form.TextField({
                fieldLabel: 'Email',
                /* snip */
            }),
        {
            boxLabel: 'Is One',
            /* snip */
        }
    ],
```

I'm basing this off of the Ext 3.3 documentation, so you'll need to adjust for the version you're using.

Comment: There is no need to create components by reference like this. The OP's issue is in the use of `inputType` instead of the correct `xtype`.